# In redis, how to remove a particular value for a key

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have below values for key google.com, how can I delete **109** from the table? I tried with **del** command, but it deletes all values.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall google.com
1) "57"
2) "58"
3) "109"
4) "258"
5) "414"
127.0.0.1:6379> del google.com "109"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall google.com
(empty array)
```

Answer (score 2):

it's a hash, so you should use HDEL.

https://redis.io/commands/hdel

Comment: thanks! I thought it's string